# How to make label with multiple stars for statistical significance in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

Currently, I have this code to include a *, **, and a *** in a legend

```
plt.plot([], [], '*', label="p < .05", color='black')
plt.plot([], [], '**', label="p < .01", color='black')
plt.plot([], [], '***', label="p < .005", color='black')
```

And am getting this error

```
ValueError: Illegal format string "**"; two marker symbols
```

Because a * is a marker symbol in matplotlib. However, I would like to make markers for ** as well as ***. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Just found the answer. I used some latex styling for matplotlib to add the 3 asterisks. They each had different sizes as well, so I included code to change the sizes

```
plt.scatter([], [], marker=r'$\ast$', label="p < .05",
            color='black', linestyle='None')
plt.scatter([], [], marker=r'$\ast\ast$', label="p < .01",
            color='black', linestyle='None', s=600)
plt.scatter([], [], marker=r'$\ast\ast\ast$',
            label="p < .005", color='black', linestyle='None', s=750)
```